# database is getting locked on insert statements

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I have a problem when I try to insert into my sqlite db. I have two tables looking like this :

```
CREATE TABLE user(UId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT ,name VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE,phoneNumber INTEGER UNIQUE);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE 'transaction'(TId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT , loan REAL, trackUser INTEGER,FOREIGN KEY(trackUser) REFERENCES user(UId));
```

I can insert into the user table without any problems like this:

```
INSERT INTO user (name, phoneNumber) VALUES(@name,@phoneNumber)
```

But when I try to add a transaction my database gets locked. I do that like this:

```
    public void Add(Transaction trans,User user)
    {
        _conn.Open();
        string SQL = "INSERT INTO 'transaction' (loan, trackUser) VALUES(@loan,@userID);";
        string checkUserSQL = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE UId = @UId) LIMIT 1;";
        SQLiteCommand checkUserCommand = new SQLiteCommand(checkUserSQL,_conn);
        checkUserCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@UId", user.UId));
        var reader = checkUserCommand.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        var check = reader.GetBoolean(0);
        if (!check)
        {
            throw new UserDoesNotExcistException();
        }
        SQLiteCommand transCommand = new SQLiteCommand(SQL, _conn);
        transCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@loan",trans.Loan));
        transCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@userID",user.UId));
        transCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _conn.Close();
    }
```

the select statement that checks if the user exicst runs without a problem but when it comes to `transCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` the db gets locked. Am I binding the forign key in a wrong way or why is my db getting locked?

Comment: You should close the previous reader before starting another one on the same connection. Try inserting a `reader.Close()` after the check, and remember to close the `transCommand` one too. You really should be wrapping them in `using` statements to make things neater and worry less about resource clean up.

Comment: transCommand isn't a reader though? I have tried to add the reader.close just before the creation of the transcommand but it still gets locked

Comment: What exactly is the error that you are getting? Is it always on the first run through this method, or after you've run it once already? `transCommand` is still a command object that needs to be closed.

Comment: I can't seem to find a close command on transCommand though? The exact error is: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll

Additional information: database is locked"

Comment: You are right, I was thinking you were running an execute reader. Are you locking it somewhere else by not disposing or closing the command object or connection? How do you open the connection (connection string)?

Comment: Ah I was reading from the db earlier and didnt close the reader. I will start wrapping them up in using statements instead. Thank you for the help!